# external program failed in nant script

Tags: windows, node.js, selenium, nant

I have modified a working build script called mybuild.build with nant, I added a call to an external program (node.exe). Trying to startup the selenium webdriver:

```
<property name="node.path" value="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" />
<exec program="${node.path}" commandline="webdriver-manager start">
</exec>
```

The node.exe works when I start it from the windows commandline. When running this command:

```
nant mybuild.build
```

It throws up an error:

```
External Program Failed: c:\program files\nodejs\node.exe (return code was 8)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: set `verbose="true"` in the `exec` task - it should hopefully give you more information in the nant output about what's happened

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be the space in "Program Files".

Try this

```
<property name="node.path" value="&quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe&quot;" />
```